# How to gather specific columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation, recode

I am manipulating my dataset in a tidyverse fashion. However, the `recode` function at the end was not working. Here is an example:

```
olddata <- data.frame(
       x = rep(1,12),
       var_a = sample(1:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
       var_b = sample(1:10, 12, replace = TRUE),
       var_c = sample(1:10, 12, replace = TRUE))

newdata <- olddata %>%
  gather(var, type, var_a:var_c) %>%
  separate(var, into = c("var", "role"), sep = -1) %>%
  recode(role, "a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=3)
```

Error message says

> Error in UseMethod("recode") : no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recode is a function that returns a vector. If you're aiming for a tidyverse workflow, you can use a mutate function to get the desired result

```
newdata <- olddata %>%
  gather(var, type, var_a:var_c) %>%
  separate(var, into = c("var", "role"), sep = -1) %>%
  mutate( role = recode(role, "a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=3))

head(newdata)
  x  var role type
1 1 var_    1    3
2 1 var_    1    5
3 1 var_    1    2
4 1 var_    1    4
5 1 var_    1   10
6 1 var_    1    7
```

Answer (score 4):

`gather` has been retired. If you use the `pivot_longer` function it can combine `gather` and `separate` step together here.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

olddata %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -x, 
               names_to = c('var', 'role'), 
               names_pattern = '(var_)(.*)') %>%
  mutate(role = recode(role, "a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=3))

#       x var    role value
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1 var_      1     6
# 2     1 var_      2     1
# 3     1 var_      3     9
# 4     1 var_      1     4
# 5     1 var_      2     6
# 6     1 var_      3     7
# 7     1 var_      1     5
# 8     1 var_      2     8
# 9     1 var_      3     8
#10     1 var_      1     7
# … with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Nice. I think you posted the output before running the mutate statement though - `role` is supposed to display integers, right?

Comment: That's right. Updated the answer to include `role` as integers. Thanks @William